# How can I use javascript to check what's the color and size of the windbreaker and send a email when paypal approves the payment

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

As you can see on my website [here](http://hyun.x10host.com/vetements/Windbreaker_Script.html), I have a working paypal button that accepts payments when I buy on sandbox (You can test it yourself with the email: *hyunsupply@armyspy.com* and password: *Hyuntest*), but what I want to also send a email to myself (or the owner of the website) of the size and color so I can know what to manufacture or send. How can I use javascript to check what's the color (radio button) and size of the windbreaker (list with css and javascript that makes it look like a dropdown) and send a email with that info and preferably the order id or address (or some way I can know which order is which). I tried to use if along with answers I found online but the alert doesn't show up to test that the if works. I have worked with php before and I know how to make php send a email with variables and stuff but I don't know how I would approach this with javascript or if theres a way to do this paypal stuff in php.

```
<main>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 60%;">
                <div class="product-photo">
                    <img class="small" style="z-index: 1;" src="images/Windbreaker_white (Back).png">
                    <img class="big" style="z-index: 2;" src="images/Windbreaker_white (Front).png">
                </div>
            </th>
            <th style="padding: 0px 100px 0px 0px;">
                <div style="right: 10%;">
                    <img class="Script_text" src="images/Script_text.png" style="margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;">
                    <div class="wrap-drop" id="noble-gases" align="left" style="z-index: 101; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <span class="size">Select your size</span>
                        <ul class="drop">
                            <li>X-Small</li>
                            <li>Small</li>
                            <li>Medium</li>
                            <li>Large</li>
                            <li>X-Large</li>
                            <li>XX-Large</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div align="right">
                        <ul class="product-color" style="z-index: 100;">
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" name="color" id="black" style="z-index: 100;" />
                                <label for="black" style="background-color:rgb(22, 22, 22); z-index: 100;"></label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" name="color" id="white" style="z-index: 100;" checked="checked" />
                                <label for="white" style="background-color:rgb(196, 196, 196); z-index: 100;"></label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="paypal-button-container" style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px"></div>

                    <script>
                        paypal.Buttons({
                            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                                return actions.order.create({
                                    purchase_units: [{
                                        amount: {
                                            value: '70.00'
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                            },

                            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                                    var BlackCheckbox = document.getElementById("black");

                                    if (BlackCheckbox.checked == true) {
                                        if ($('.size').find('span:contains("X-Small")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the extra small black windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Small")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the small black windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Medium")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the medium black windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Large")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the large black windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("X-Large")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the extra large black windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("XX-Large")')
                                            .length != 0) {
                                            alert(
                                                'Its the double extra large black windbreaker'
                                            );
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if ($('.size').find('span:contains("X-Small")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the extra small white windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Small")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the small white windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Medium")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the medium white windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("Large")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the large white windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("X-Large")').length !=
                                            0) {
                                            alert('Its the extra large white windbreaker');
                                        } else if ($('.size').find('span:contains("XX-Large")')
                                            .length != 0) {
                                            alert(
                                                'Its the double extra large white windbreaker'
                                            );
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                                    return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
                                        method: 'post',
                                        body: JSON.stringify({
                                            orderID: data.orderID
                                        })
                                    });
                                });
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: 'white',
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                shape: 'rect',
                                label: 'pay',
                                height: 55
                            },

                        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                    </script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        PAYPAL_CLIENT = 'PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT';
                        PAYPAL_SECRET = 'PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET';

                        PAYPAL_OAUTH_API = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/';
                        PAYPAL_ORDER_API = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/';

                        basicAuth = base64encode(`${ PAYPAL_CLIENT }:${ PAYPAL_SECRET }`);
                        auth = http.post(PAYPAL_OAUTH_API, {
                            headers: {
                                Accept: `application/json`,
                                Authorization: `Basic ${ basicAuth }`
                            },
                            data: `grant_type=client_credentials`
                        });

                        function handleRequest(request, response) {

                            orderID = request.body.orderID;

                            details = http.get(PAYPAL_ORDER_API + orderID, {
                                headers: {
                                    Accept: `application/json`,
                                    Authorization: `Bearer ${ auth.access_token }`
                                }
                            });

                            if (details.error) {
                                return response.send(500);
                            }

                            if (details.purchase_units[0].amount.value !== '5.77') {
                                return response.send(400);
                            }

                            database.saveTransaction(orderID);

                            return response.send(200);
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Did you really shared your real password?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi no its only a sandbox account meaning I can delete it at anytime. Also, right now, the website is running sandbox so you can't buy/pay for anything (It's only meant for testing). It has like 500000 fake dollars just to test out the payment system don't worry haha

Comment: You can using ajax to send detail order like (size, color, email, address) and then you `$_POST` all data and process it (insert to your DB or direct mail to you). You can send email using [mail](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) from php or using phpmailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you append the color and the size of the item in the body in this call?

```
return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    orderID: data.orderID
  })
});
```

You `onApprove` function changes to:

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    var BlackCheckbox = document.getElementById("black");
    // Getting the color by checking if the checkbox `black` is checked or not
    var color = (BlackCheckbox.checked === true) ? 'black' : 'white';
    // Finding the size by seeing which size the user has selected from the dropdown.
    var size = $('span.size').text();

    //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
    return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID,
        color: color,
        size: size
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm still a beginner in javascript and I got my code from the paypal docs so I'm not sure about all of this. First question is what do I put instead of <COLOR VALUE>  and <SIZE>. Am I suppose to have variables that change according to what color/size I pick. Also, what does all of this allow me to do? Does it automatically send it in my paypal dashboard or something. Sorry if I'm a beginner and all of this sounds obvious.

Comment: Your entire `onApprove` function is basically checking for size and color and alerting it on the client. I'll update my answer to include the values for <COLOR VALUE> and <SIZE>

Comment: @TahaInc, I've updated my answer to fetch those values and send it in the request. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: So I tried that and the color works fine but, unfortunately the size registers as undefined. I tried this alert to see the variable values:  `alert('Its the ' + color + ' and ' + size + ' and ' + data.orderID + ' windbreaker');` but the size comes out as undefined. Here is a [picture of the error] (https://i.imgur.com/MYmHDRr.png)